# How to detect whether Bis-B is through carrier or Wi-Fi programatically?

Tags: blackberry

How do we programatically detect whether the BIS data traffic is routed through the carrier network or Wi-Fi. Looking at the BB logo dots, we can see that it will be near Wi-Fi indicator if data is routed through Wi-Fi, and near the carrier signal indicator if the data is routed through the carrier data network.

Is there a way to detect that programatically?

Comment: My usual comment - why do you need it?

Comment: @EugenMartynov  I don't want any traffic to go through wi-fi , hence. I have disabled Wi-Fi transport using "setDisallowedTransportTypes" but this will not disable data going through Wi-Fi when i am on BIS-B. what do you think? Can i disable data going through wifi for BIS-B?

Comment: Would turning the Wi-Fi off satisfy your requirement? If so see net.rim.device.api.system.Radio.deactivateWAFs()

Comment: Is it because you are afraid about security through wifi? I don't see point why you don't allow bis-b over wifi. As well wifi transport is something different that meaning that trafic is going over wifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect whether BIS is going through Wi-Fi, use

```
if (CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_BIS_B)) { 

       if (CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_BIS_B, RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN, false))
       {
             //BIS-B going through wifi 
       }
       else
       {
            //BIS-B going through carrier
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the API to determine if a particular service is capable of carrying BIS-B or BES traffic. Since BIS-B and BES are automatically routed through the least expensive means, if Wi-Fi is capable of carrying it BIS-B will go by Wi-Fi.

The [KB article](http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/KB13368) in Mister Smiths's comment specifies BIS-B access is available with a qualifying data plan (AKA a BlackBerry data plan, BlackBerry bolt on, etc

> "To connect to the BlackBerry Data Services over Wi-Fi for PIN
>   messaging and BlackBerry Internet Service connectivity, the BlackBerry
>   smartphone requires a BlackBerry data plan from the wireless service
>   provider..."

). Given a qualifying data plan BlackBerry Internet Service (BIS) is available under all conditions specified in the chart. If the Wi-Fi connection supports a connection to the BlackBerry router at the ROC then BIS will travel via that connection unless a better option is available. One such better option is also known as "wireless bypass". When a BlackBerry in connected (by USB or BlueTooth) to a PC with internet access and Desktop Manager installed, the BlackBerry will use the PC internet connection.

The KB article also mentions BES. It is often helpful to think of BIS/BIS-B as a subset of BES capability hosted at a RIM Operations Center. Both BES and BIS/BIS-B make use of the BlackBerry router capabilities. The BlackBerry will automatically seek out the apparent least cost method of connecting with the BlackBerry Router either BES or BIS/BIS-B. In order of preference that is: wireless bypass; Wi-Fi; wireless carrier.

Comment: Richard, bis-b goes through the wifi only for supported carriers, it also depends on the service books in the device. It doesn't always go through wi-Fi if wi-Fi is available. Is there a way to detect if it is going through wi-fi?

Comment: Do you have documentation to support that? The documentation on the RIM developers' site says otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling Wi-Fi:

```
Radio.deactivateWAFs(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN);
```

Maybe you could also detect if Wi-Fi is active calling `RadioInfo.getActiveWAFs`, but how would you know if it is your app the one using the connection?

Comment: yes i might end up doing that. We can also detect whether bis is going through Wi-Fi but we cannot ask bb to route bis through carrier only.